# Is there a name for this vocal effect? If so, what is it and how can I apply it?

Tags: effects, vocals

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I heard this vocal effect in a song (linked here: [YouTube Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vnx88Eku_1s&feature=youtu.be)) and I know I've heard it before in other songs.

It's kind of a like a gritty-sounding radio effect? I'm not sure how to describe it.

I'd like some help identifying it and, if at all possible, figure out how to apply it to some vocal clips I have sitting around.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks! :)